# Change the target VM ScaleSet in an existing and running Azure DevOps Agent Pool?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-vm-scale-set

Cheers!

Maybe some of you already have done something similar.

We created a dedicated, self hosted AZ DevOps Agent Pool in one of our subscriptions with terraform.

So terraform being terraform and DevOps doing its magic with the agent pools, any major update on the scale set for now results to a recreation of the scale set with corresponding downtime. We know about the necessary `ignore_changes` lifecycle changes which would probably prevent that, but they are not yet implemented.

So my question is: has anyone experience how AZ DevOps reacts when you change the target Scale Set of a running Agent Pool?
Meaning just changing the target ScaleSet via the Azure DevOps Portal.

A little downtime is fine with we but we would really love to being able to deploy the new infra running parallel to the old agent set and then switch via the portal. Like a standard Blue/Green deployment scheme.

Also having a fallback to the old agent pool would be a major bonus.

As long as an Agent Pools doesn't support more than 1 scale sets that seemed to be the most viable solution.

Anyone here ever tried anything like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:
We just pulled the plug and switched over to a new Scale Set.
The downtime is immediately, because DevOps scales the "old" scale set to 0 right after.
After approximately 10-15 minutes Azure DevOps started to scale the new instances up and added them to the agent pool.
So in a nutshell: Blue/Green deployment of the Scale Set worked basically. You can schedule new jobs while the agents are down but running at the time of the switch are terminated as the instances are deleted right away